# Drop the "fn:" in MarkLogic functions?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Is there a way with MarkLogic to not have to prefix every single `fn:` function with that prefix?  I've seen lots of codes on the Internet that show me that I don't need it.

Things can get rather verbose, you know?   `fn:not(fn:contains(...))`, instead of `not(contains(...))`

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like you, I prefer not to type `fn:` in front of all my fn:functions.

In normal XQuery main modules you don't need the `fn:` prefix because that's the *default function namespace* and used for all unprefixed functions.  You *do* however need `fn:` in library modules because they change their *default function namespace* to that of the library module namespace.  This means the library functions can call each other without any prefix.

But you can change it back!  Here's the header code to do the switch back.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace util = "http://markmail.org/util";
declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";
```

Or if you're on the older 0.9-ml:

```
xquery version "0.9-ml"
module "http://markmail.org/util"
declare namespace util = "http://markmail.org/util"
default function namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/xpath-functions"
```

It puts the module in a given namespace, assigns util to that namespace, then assigns the default back to the normal `fn:` one.

After this switch, function calls and definitions without a prefix will default to the `fn:` prefix; that means all functions in the `util` library should explicitly use a `util:` prefix.  (Personally, I think that's cleaner anyway.)

Comment: There's a feature coming in V7 that will allow you to specify a set of default namespaces for a given application server and I believe the default set now includes fn.

Comment: Sweet.  Didn't know that about that in the main modules.  Works as advertised there.

However, the switch doesn't work.  I'm on ML5, and I get this error when trying the code you provided: "Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected StringLiteral_, expecting Namespace_".  I assume this is related to the ML version.

Comment: OK, using your code there as a model, I think I got it:

    module namespace my-namespace = '<my-namespace>';
    declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";

Comment: Yeah, MarkMail was written against xquery version "0.9-ml" and you're on "1.0-ml" probably.  I'll tweak my answer.

Comment: Now... if there were also a way to pull in functx functions into the default namespace as well... heh :)   ...  thanks for your help!